# Fatal: pathspec 'file.name' did not match any files

Tags: git

I'm a complete beginner with no previous coding experience and just started to learn `git add`, `push`, `commit` single and multiple files.

I have already created a directory and a file name and have tried to use '**`git add file.name`**' to then be able to add it together with the other one's I already created, but it doesn't add it, or even show up when I do '**`git status`**'.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?
I should mention that since I did keep messing up previously, I deleted the file before.

Comment: You can't `git add` a file that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

> I should mention that since i did keep messing up previously, i deleted the file before.

First, recreate the file.
Then do a `git status` to see if it appears as untracked.

If not, check if it is ignored with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- file.name
```

(replace `file.name` by the actual file name)

This assume you are in a folder part of a local git repository, initialized with [`git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init)